# How to reload __init__ files in FastApi every 5 minutes using the docker --reload?

Tags: python, docker, fastapi

I'm trying to use the parameter --reload in my dockerfile to reload files inside the **init** function every 5 minutes in my FastAPI code, but i cannot seem to achieve that. Someone knows what i'm doing wrong?

version: "3.9"

```
services:
  people:
    container_name: people
    build: .
    working_dir: /code/app
    command: uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --reload
    environment:
      DEBUG: 1
    volumes:
      - ./app:/code/app
    ports:
      - 8008:8000
    restart: on-failure
```

And the **init** code:

```
class Files:
    def __init__(self):
       df = # here i will load file from an azure bucket...
```

Also, i don't want to restart the whole container and rebuild it, but just reload the file.

Comment: Would a non-Docker Python virtual environment work better for you?  That would give you an isolated set of packages so you can `pip install` without interfering with the system Python, but it actually uses your local filesystem so you don't need to work around Docker's isolation features.

Comment: The `--reload`-parameter is for detecting that a python file on disk has changed - it does not reinitialize the application if nothing changes. Do you want something like apscheduler to instead download and update functionality inside your app on regular intervals?